# Set application theme globally in android

Tags: android, android-theme

I am setting theme for each activity seperately in the corresponding activity.java file.

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
```

Can i set the theme globally in the manifest file and then override it to change action bar background color etc.

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

In styles.xml

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
```

But it crashes.Why?

Comment: paste your exception detail please.

Comment: "it crashes" it not enough information to diagnose a problem. Please add the LogCat of the error in order for other to help you.

Answer (score 0):

as per my guessing it is happening
 cause your using theme which is not supporting to actionbar and your calling actionbar related code in such activity i mean your app may be crashing in that activity where you write actionbar related code but unfortunately the theme for that activity is not actionbar related theme thats why may be it comes

use actionbar related theme in that activity using

```
 android:theme="@style/actionbar supported theme"
```

line in manifest against that activity

Comment: What is an actionbar supported theme.When i set setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light); in the java file, it doesnt crash

Comment: then use same one for that activity dont use unsupported actionbar theme else it will definately crash

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html  use this link to know actionbar supportied theme